# Update the Jar files which i am using in my application dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, jar

In my application, I am using external jars of other applications. When this other application is updated, the jar files that I use in my application also gets updated dynamically.
I need help with this. Do we have any code in Java for dynamic updation of  referenced jar files ?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically update other jars during runtime, or do you have problems building when dependent libraries are updated?

Comment: Do these apps. have a GUI?

Comment: Yes I have problem in building when dependent libraries are updated..

Answer (score 0):

You should use separate class loaders to load the jar files dynamically, if there is  a newer version available, use a new class loader.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) scripts to do that. There are tags that can be used to copy from one project to another. Also, you can generate jar files at runtime.